# Efficient random sampling

Tags: python, math, random

My problem is simple: 
I've an array with 20 million floats. In that array, every float has a probability *p* of being randomly altered.

The simples way to do so is to move through the array, doing if (rand(0,1) < p) then modify.

However, even paralelizing, its slow as hell,  and I was thinking if there's a faster way to randomly obtain some indexes to modify.

My first thought was to pick up p * n random numbers, where n is the total number of floats in the array, however, that doesnt exactly represent the probability distribution, as nothing in the first case guarantees that only p*n floats will be modified.

Ideas?

PD: I'm using python for the implementation, probably someone had this problem before and implemented something in the libraries, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Is `p` very small?

Comment: yes, p is small, 0.01 to 0.1 (1-10% chance of modification)

Comment: @DyZ I think that is for generating random numbers, right? I've an EXISTING array, of lets say 20 million elements. Each element has a probability of p of being modified. I've to randomly modify them, and the final array needs to be a 20 million element array. Elements not modified will contain their old value, while modified elements will have a randomly generated new one. I could use np.random.choice(20000000, n, replace=False), howver, I still need a way to properly calculate n, and with those index modify manually

Comment: Is `p` the same for all numbers?

Comment: "My first thought was to pick up p * n random numbers, [...] however, that doesnt exactly represent the probability distribution, as nothing in the first case guarantees that only p*n floats will be modified." Is this really an issue? With 20 million items, the actual numbers of picked elements will be _very_ close, anyway. I just tried with n=20e6 and p=0.3 and got 6000376 modified elements, within 0.06% of the estimated 600000. So if p is small, as you said, I think this _is_a good approach.

Comment: Also, in order to find more efficient approaches, you should show what exactly you are doing right now., e.g. are you using loops, list comprehension, or numpy, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if p is high, i.e. >= 0.5, you won't save much time whatever you're doing because you're still likely to visit most of the elements.  If p is lower, though, you can draw from a [binomial distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) with n=20M and your probability to determine how many elements to touch.

```
In [23]: np.random.binomial(20*10**6, 0.1)
Out[23]: 1999582

In [24]: np.random.binomial(20*10**6, 0.99999)
Out[24]: 19999801

In [25]: np.random.binomial(20*10**6, 0.5)
Out[25]: 10001202

In [26]: np.random.binomial(20*10**6, 0.0001)
Out[26]: 1986
[...]
In [30]: np.random.binomial(20*10**6, 0.0001)
Out[30]: 1989

In [31]: np.random.binomial(20*10**6, 0.0001)
Out[31]: 1988
```

This number is the number of successes assuming n trials each with p chance of success, which is your situation exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a random array with values in `[0,1)` of the same size `n` as your data vector using

```
rnd = np.random.rand(n)
```

Now you check at which indices these random values are smaller than `p`

```
mask = rnd < p
```

and now change the data at all indices that have been included by the mask, e.g.:

```
data[mask]=np.random.rand(data[mask].size)
```

or using any method you want to alter the data.

Comment: Is this quicker?

Comment: Should be quicker than iterating through the array in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Your array:

```
array = np.random.random(size=100) # Whatever
```

An array of random 0/1's:

```
p = 0.05 # Could be an array itself
markers = np.random.binomial(1, p, array.shape[0])
```

An array of indexes of the values to be modified:

```
locations = np.where(markers)[0]
# Something like array([19, 29, 32, 67, 68, 71])
```

You loop through the original array using those indexes or modify all values at once with something like `array[locations] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

This runs ~4 sec / round on my machine

```
import random

rand = random.random
p = 0.1
TOTAL_ROUND = 10

x = [rand() for i in xrange(20000000)]

for i in range(TOTAL_ROUND):
    print "round", i
    x = [rand() if val < p else val for val in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If p is small, you can save a lot of time by using `numpy.random.geometric` to provide a sample of distances between elements being altered.

A simple pass over the array ary:

```
from numpy.random import geometric

index = -1
while True:
  index += geometric(0.01)
  if index >= len(ary):
    break
  ary[ind] = # compute new value
```

Numpy distribution functions can produce an array of return values, so as long as p is small, it's probably even faster to produce all the step values at once:

```
from numpy import cumsum
from numpy.random import geometric

for index in cumsum(geometric(p, size=int(len(ary) * p * 1.1))):
  if index < len(ary):
    ary[index] = # compute new value
```

The 1.1 is a fudge factor to make sure enough samples are selected from the geometric distribution. For large arrays it should be fine, but it is not guaranteed. A better (albeit more complicated) solution would be to generate the samples in chunks of, say, 10000 and keep doing that until you manage to get to the end of the array.